# Wrong Calculations of Mass Density Function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

**The answers yet don't answer my question.**

Let $A$ be the set in $R^2$ bounded between the lines $y=0, x=y$ and $x=2$.

Let $(X, Y)$ be jointly continuous random variables with pdf $f(x,y)=cxy^2$ for $x,y$ in $A$

Q: Find $c$ and $P(X>1)$

---

My solution:

I know that $\int\int f(x,y)=1$ so: $\int\int f(x,y) = \int\int (cxy^2) dx dy= \int_0^2\int_0^y (cxy^2) dx dy = \int_0^2 (cy^2y^2)/2 dy = \int_0^2 (cy^4)/2 dy = c*2^5/10 = 32c/10 = 1 $ so: c=10/32

From here:

$f_X(x)=10/32 xy^2$

$P(X>1)=1-P(X<=1)=1-F_X(1)=...$

$F_X(x)=\int_0^x 10/32 xy^2 dy= 10/32 x^4/3$

But I'm getting stragne answer for $P(X>1)$ instead of the so-clear answer of $3/4...$ Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Your work looks good.

You are assuming that $P(X>1) = 3/4$ based on the area, I assume.  But this is not a uniform distribution!  The probability density gets higher as you move to the right, so it makes perfect sense that the answer would be greater than $3/4$.

Comment: Hi, "this is not a uniform distribution" why is that? the whole area is 2, so after x=1 3/4 of the values are there...

Comment: Now I see why you are right, but still I'm interested to know what did I do wrong?

Comment: The point of having that function $cxy^2$ is expressly stating that the distribution is not uniform.  The function is designed so that higher values of both $x$ and $y$ are more likely.  Your calculations are correct.  Your conclusion that you are wrong, is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your limits of integration are wrong. Use: $f_X(x)=\int_0^{x} cxy^{2}dy$ for $0 <x<2$  and $P(X>1)=\int_1^{2} f_X(x)dx$.

Comment: You mistyped $=$ as $-$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm more interested in knowing what did I do wrong rather than looking for other method.

Comment: @Dan It is not another method.  You just had the wrong bounds for your integrals $A=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2: 0\leq y\leq x\leq 2\}$ since it is $\triangle\langle 0,0\rangle\langle 2,0\rangle\langle 2,2\rangle$. So $$\begin{align}1&=\int_0^2\int_y^2 cxy^2\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm dy&&=\int_0^2\int_0^x cxy^2\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\[2ex]\mathsf P(X>1)&=\int_1^2\int_0^x \tfrac{15}{32}xy^2\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\end{align}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Is this notation for triangle area standard?

Comment: Yes.  It's the coordinates of the vertices. @Shahab